# What does Alex Krycek say as he is dying?

Tags: the-x-files

I feel a bit silly asking this because he has just been shot in the forehead, not point-blank but pretty close to it. But then stranger things have happened in the series. He also looks at Mulder after making the sound.

<sup>***Here it is, a few seconds in ( @3m21s ):***</sup>

If it was slightly more random, I would dismiss it as a spasm, but it really does sound like he is attempting to communicate something.

I have replayed this part over and over trying to figure out what he says or is trying to say. But then I thought it could be a Russian word or phrase, which I wouldn't know.

I'm hoping there are some die-hard fans here who know conclusively whether it's a spasm or some word.

I've searched for an answer on that internet, but couldn't find *any* references to it, which usually means I'm on my own! Especially considering it's quite a high-profile TV moment. Maybe your kung fu is superior?

Comment: I should imagine it's some variation on "*Oh my God, I can't believe you shot me in the head*"

Comment: “Fire up the boat! I’m jumping the shark!”

Comment: nothing in the scripts that I can find

Comment: @NKCampbell OK Thanks. Must just be overacting or something.

Answer (score -1):

After listening to it several times, I think Krycek gasps *John* with his dying breath but I am far from certain.  I don't remember enough to say whether that makes sense in the context of this episode or not.